# Calling Cocoa IBAction from Carbon Code

Tags: cocoa, macos-carbon, ibaction

I'm trying to call a Cocoa `IBAction` from Carbon code...

I've set up global keys using [this tutorial](http://dbachrach.com/blog/2005/11/program-global-hotkeys-in-cocoa-easily/).

The hot keys are working fine, but I need to fire an IBAction when the global key has been pressed.

I keep getting errors when I use

```
[self functionName]
```

How do I call the function?

I've read about passing the Cocoa controller to the carbon method. How would I do this? or what is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're calling `[self functionName]` in a Carbon Event handler callback.  That's not an Objective-C method, so of course `self` is not defined.

When you install a Carbon Event handler, one of the parameters is a "user data" pointer.  You can pass an Objective-C object pointer in this parameter, so that your event handler will get it, and you can say something like `[(MyController*) inUserData functionName]`.  Of course, to make this work, your handler must be in an Objective-C or Objective-C++ source file.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass one of these as your user data while keeping the program safe for c++ translations:

```
/* include the necessary C header, located in objc/ (objc/objc.h?) */

/* of course, definitions with objc messaging belong in your .mm file */

class t_ibaction_invocation {

/* you may want to retain d_target or d_optionalArgument, and release at destruction */
    enum { RetainArguments = 0 };
public:

/* IBAction takes the form: [target action:optionalArgument]; */

    t_ibaction_invocation(id target, SEL action, id optionalArgument) : d_target(target), d_action(action), d_optionalArgument(optionalArgument) {
        assert(this->d_target);
        if (RetainArguments) {
            [this->d_target retain];
            [this->d_optionalArgument retain];
        }
    }

    ~t_ibaction_invocation() {
        if (RetainArguments) {
            [this->d_target release], target = 0;
            [this->d_optionalArgument release], optionalArgument = 0;
        }
    }

    id performAction() {
        if (this->d_target && this->d_action) {
            return [this->d_target performSelector:this->d_action withObject:this->d_optionalArgument];
        }
        else {
            assert(d_target && d_action);
            return 0;
        }
    }

private:
    id d_target;
    SEL d_action;
    id d_optionalArgument;
};
```